# Compare iFrame ID from within iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, if-statement, identity

I would like to compare the parent iFrame ID from within the iFrame, something like the following would be placed inside the iFrame...

```
if(window.Id === 'fancybox-content') {
//scripts
}
else {
//scripts
}
```

Does anybody know a way to get the iFrame ID because window.Id is of course not working.

My iFrame is on the same domains as the parent window by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.frameElement.id
```

will get the iframe id.

Comment: I may have found this solution in Google Search Results, but what is the browser compatibility on that method?

Comment: here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.frameElement#Browser_compatibility